# Check if string present in same sub list python

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this.

```
l=[[['item1','item2'],[int1,int2]], [['item3','item4'],[int1,int2]]]
```

I want to check If **item1** & **item2** both are same or not..

Currently, I'm following a approach extracting first element in sub list & Thereby counting occurrence..But I feel like It's long approach. Can I know if there is any easy way to do it?

```
f=[e[0] for e in l[:1]]
print(f)
```

output

```
['item1']
```

**Expected output.**
if item1 & Item2 are same.

```
Both item1 & Item2 are same
```

if item1 & Item2 are not same.

```
Both item1 & Item2 are not same
```

Comment: Do you need a triple-nested list here? Because `l[1:]` is empty here and your code makes no sense...

Comment: Do you need to compare item3 and item4, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case that you want to compare all the 'item's in the list, you can loop the list and compare first item with second item like this:

```
l = [
    [['item2','item2'], [int,int]],
    [['item3','item4'], [int,int]]
]

for item in l:
    if item[0][0] == item[0][1]:
        print(f"Both {item[0][0]} & {item[0][1]} are same")
    else:
        print(f"Both {item[0][0]} & {item[0][1]} are not same")

#This code will print:
#Both item2 & item2 are same
#Both item3 & item4 are not same
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple check for whether all the elements in a list are the same is

```
len(set(l)) == 1
```

So if you need to check if each element of a list contains idenitcal elements:

```
result = [len(set(s)) == 1 for s in l[0]]
```

This returns a list of booleans, which you can then transform into strings or whatever you want. For example:

```
for b in result:
    print(f'Both item1 & item2 are {"" if b else "not "} the same')
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks Mad physicist that was a nice explanation.:)